# Google Universal Analytics - Development & Debugging Tools

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

Developing and testing GA event tracking code can be frustrating to say the least. When testing the code you can see if there is any JavaScript page errors but you can't really see what the GA Tracking Beacon that you're sending really looks like and if it was sent successfully. It can also take quite a long time for your events to show up in your GA Console.

Does anyone know of any tools that exist that could help me see the beacons that I'm sending to Google and see if the transmission is successful?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great browser plugin for Chrome called [Google Analytics Debugger.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en)

It is very easy to debugging tool. It prints useful information to the Javascript console.  These messages include error messages and warnings which can tell you when your analytics tracking code is set up incorrectly.  In addition, it provides a detailed breakdown of each tracking beacon sent to Google Analytics.

It provides instant code validation and has saved me hours of debugging and testing time.

There is also a plug in for Firefox called [GA Debugger](http://keithclark.co.uk/labs/google-analytics-debugger/). I have not used it but it may be worth a try if you're using Firefox.